# How to test object from factory with mocha with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, sinon

### Background

I have a factory function that creates dogs that bark:

```
const dogFactory = () => {
    const bark = name => console.log(`${name} just barked!`);

    return{
        bark
    };
};
```

One would use it like:

```
const dog = dogFactory();
dog.bark("boby"); //"boby just barked!"
```

I also have an hotel of dogs. Business is not going good, so to keep appearances I am creating my own dogs ! This hotel thus takes a `dogFactory` as an argument and looks like the following:

```
const dogHotel = deps => {
    const {
        dogFactory
    } = deps;

    let dogsHosted = [];

    const feed = () => {
        dogsHosted.push(dogFactory());
        dogsHosted.forEach( (dog, i) => dog.bark(i));
    }

    return{
        feed
    };  
};
```

You would use it like:

```
const hotelAwsome = dogHotel({dogFactory: dogFactory});
hotelAwsome.feed();
```

This hotel feeds dogs. Because there is no business it creates a dog and then feeds everyone. Every time a dog is fed, it barks of happiness!

### Problem

One would think that creating infinite dogs in a broken hotel would be the problem, but that is not the case!

The problem here is that I want to make sure the dogs are happy barking. That is, that for each dog in the hotel `bark` is being called.

### Code

This is currently my test. I am using `mocha` as a test suite, I am using `sinon` to spy on my fake factory objects:

```
const sinon = require( "sinon" );
const chai = require( "chai" );
const expect = chai.expect;

describe("dog hotel", () => {

    const fakeFacory = () => {
        const bark = () => sinon.spy()
        return {bark};
    };

    it("should make the dogs bark with happiness when feeding them!", () => {
        const hotelAweomse = dogHotel({dogFactory: fakeFacory});
        hotelAwesome.feed();
        //expect something here 
    });
});
```

The issue here is that I am passing a fake dog factory, but I can't check with sinon if the dog are barking or not!

### Question

How do I test if the dogs that are created in the hotel, are barking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the spy creation out of the fake factory. Now you can just use the spy [properties](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/spies/#properties) (callOnce, calls) in the expect.

**Kudos for the entertaining question :)**

```
describe("dog hotel", () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(); // create the spy outside

    const fakeFacory = () => {
        return {
          bark: spy // assign it to bark
        };
    };

    it("should make the dogs bark with happiness when feeding them!", () => {
        const hotelAweomse = dogHotel({dogFactory: fakeFacory});
        hotelAwesome.feed();

        // expect only one bark
        expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;

        // expect a number of barks
        expect(spy.calls).to.equal(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks ! I have to wait 39secs before accepting xD

Comment: The service at this dog hotel is terrible. You have to wait and wait :)